# How to add new Items to an Existing List c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am Uploading an Excel file and after reading that file getting result in this.

```
 var data = from c in excel.Worksheet<QuestionMaster>()
            select new
            {
              c.Questionname,
              c.Answer1,
              c.Answer2,
              c.Answer3,
              c.Answer4,
              c.CorrectAnswer,
            };
```

Now I need to check that any of the Column in uploaded data should not be **null**

For that My Code is:
**Question Master is the Model Class**

```
QuestionMaster questions = new QuestionMaster();
QuestionMaster temp = new QuestionMaster();
List<QuestionMaster> ques = new List<QuestionMaster>();//
  foreach (var item in data)
   {
      int i = 0;
     if (item.Questionname == null || item.Answer1 == null || item.Answer2 == null ||   item.Answer3 == null || item.Answer4 == null || item.CorrectAnswer == null)
      {
          if (item.Questionname != null)
           temp.Questionname = item.Questionname.Trim();                            
         else
           temp.Questionname = "Question Name not Found in Uploaded Excel File";                            
         if (item.Answer1 != null)
           temp.Answer1 = item.Answer1.Trim();                            
         else
           temp.Answer1 = "Answer 1 Not Found in Uploaded Excel File";                            
                       \\Some more Couple of If-Else Conditions

ques.Add(temp);
      }
```

Now the Problem is :
Suppose I got three Different Rows in which their are Some Null Columns and the above conditions got true.

When **ques.add(temp)** runs **2nd or 3rd** Time it **overwrite** the other previously added List Items but the count of the number of the items added in the List remain same.
It means it is overwriting the whole list with the current data in the **temp**.

Please tell me where I am getting wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to be creating a new object in your loop every time, currently it's outside your loop so the original object keeps changing

```
  foreach (var item in data)
   {
     QuestionMaster temp = new QuestionMaster();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ques.Contains(temp))
{
    //todo replace item
}
else
{
    ques.Add(temp);
}
```

and recreate reference in loop

Comment: It will also give me the same result.

Comment: The first time it is added, it will always have the temp object as this object holds the same reference as this is being initialized before the loop. temp should be initialized inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your List conatins objects of QuestionMaster:

```
List<QuestionMaster> ques = new List<QuestionMaster>();
```

The data List has Anonym typed objects, try to create QuestionMaster objects in data instead of anynomous typed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it'll add a new item to the existing list at the end,

List authors = new List
{
new Author { Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "ADO.NET Programming", Price = 49.95 },
new Author { Name = "Neel Beniwal", Book = "Jump Ball", Price = 19.95 },
new Author { Name = "Chris Love", Book = "Practical PWA", Price = 29.95 }
};
// Add more items to the list
authors.Add(new Author { Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "Graphics with GDI+", Price = 49.95 });
authors.Add(new Author { Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "Mastering C#", Price = 54.95 });
authors.Add(new Author { Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "Jumpstart Blockchain", Price = 44.95 });

Link

> https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/add+object+to+generic+list+c%23